# Javascript Regex: how to simulate "match without capture" behavior of positive lookbehind?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a relatively simple regex problem - I need to match specific words in a string, if they are entire words or a prefix. With word boundaries, it would look something like this:

```
\b(word1|word2|prefix1|prefix2)
```

However, I can't use the word boundary condition because some words may start with odd characters, e.g. .999

My solution was to look for whitespace or starting token for these odd cases.

```
(\b|^|\s)(word1|word2|prefix1|prefix2)
```

Now words like .999 will still get matched correctly, BUT it also captures the whitespace preceding the matched words/prefixes. For my purposes, I can't have it capture the whitespace.

Positive lookbehinds seem to solve this, but javascript doesn't support them. Is there some other way I can get the same behavior to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you replacing here? If not, couldn't you just remove any leading whitespace from the resulting match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a non-capturing group using `(?:)`:

```
/(?:\b|^|\s)(word1|word2|prefix1|prefix2)/
```

UPDATE:

Based on what you want to replace it with (and @AlanMoore's good point about the `\b`), you probably want to go with this:

```
var regex = /(^|\s)(word1|word2|prefix1|prefix2)/g;
myString.replace(regex,"$1<span>$2</span>");
```

Note that I changed the first group back to a capturing one since it'll be part of the match but you want to keep it in the replacement string (right?).  Also added the `g` modifier so that this happens for all occurrences in the string (assuming thats what you wanted).

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that I tried this. For some reason, it doesn't work. When I use this regex to replace, it replaces the whitespace as well.

Comment: @DiglettPotato: What are you trying to replace it with?

Comment: string.replace( regexp, "<span>$1</span>"); -- the whitespace gets eaten up

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the terminology straight first.  A regex normally *consumes* everything it matches.  When you do a `replace()`, everything that was consumed is overwritten.  You can also *capture* parts of the matched text separately and plug them back in using `$1`, `$2`, etc.

When you were using the word boundary you didn't have to worry about this, because `\b` doesn't consume anything.  But now you're consuming the leading whitespace character if there is one, so you have to plug it back in.  I don't know what you're replacing the match with, so I'll just replace them with nothing for this demonstration.

```
result = subject.replace(/(^|\s)(word1|word2|prefix1|prefix2)/g, "$1");
```

Note that the `\b` isn't needed any more.  In fact, you *must* remove it, or it will match things like `.999` in `xyz.999`, because `\b` matches between `z` and `.`.  I'm pretty sure you don't want that.